# unable to compile ffmpeg for iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile FFmpeg for iOS (for iPhone5, in order to do some RSTP streaming stuff) following the [tutorial here](http://www.tangentsoftworks.com/blog/2012/11/12/how-to-prepare-your-mac-for-ios-development-with-ffmpeg-libraries/) but I get stuck with this error :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.
```

In my config.log file I have this :

```
BEGIN /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.D3a73otQ.c
        1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.D3a73otQ.c
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -mcpu=cortex-a9 -c -o /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.Wv4eZtHX.o /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.D3a73otQ.c
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -o /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.y84bbrJt /var/folders/9g/zv_vdz7x16g1hgx9pqj57zz80000gn/T//ffconf.Wv4eZtHX.o
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
C compiler test failed.
```

I have other errors with other scripts found on stackoverflow or with google

Any idea ?

---

Ok (i'm kinda new on mac environment), I managed to pass the configure step by fixing the sdk target to the last sdk I have (6.1), removing  Other Linker Flags but then the "make" command is full of errors (either with gcc or arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2) :

```
In file included from ./libavutil/internal.h:113,
                 from ./libavutil/common.h:385,
                 from ./libavutil/avutil.h:238,
                 from libavdevice/version.h:28,
                 from libavdevice/avdevice.h:22,
                 from libavdevice/alldevices.c:22:
./libavutil/libm.h:53: error: static declaration of ‘cbrt’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:60: error: static declaration of ‘cbrtf’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:86: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘sizeof’
./libavutil/libm.h:96: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘sizeof’
./libavutil/libm.h:142: error: static declaration of ‘rint’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:149: error: static declaration of ‘lrint’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:156: error: static declaration of ‘lrintf’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:163: error: static declaration of ‘round’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:170: error: static declaration of ‘roundf’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:177: error: static declaration of ‘trunc’ follows non-static declaration
./libavutil/libm.h:184: error: static declaration of ‘truncf’ follows non-static declaration
make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I noticed the working project had nothing set in **Other Linker Flags** whereas my not-working project had '-arch i386' set in it. I removed that and it seems to have fixed it. If problem is not resolved then unchecking **Compile for Thumb** in the project settings for the static library and the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./configure --disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=darwin --cc=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc --as='/usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk --cpu=cortex-a8 --extra-cflags='-arch armv7' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk' --enable-pic --enable-decoder=rawvideo --disable-asm
```

You also have to care about paths like "--as=/usr/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl" or ".../SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk" and adapt them to your own paths/SDK